# mySQL - Only display most common & all other column combinations show 0

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I am attempting to compute the highest number of crashes in a single race that any car had, so a car may have multiple crashes in a single race (figuratively). I've a table of crashes with the following columns:

`c_raceName`, `c_raceDate`, `c_raceId` and other irrelevants.

Firstly, to uniquely identify a race it comes in a `raceName` and `raceDate` pair. And to uniquely identify a crash you must use this pair alongside the `raceId`.

So all of these columns actually belong to another table which is our `Entry` table. This table contains the information of cars that enter the races. This table has the following columns:

`e_raceId`, `e_raceDate`, `e_raceName`, `e_raceEntryCarId`, `e_raceEntryDriverId`.

I've realised that not every race will be entered into the `Crash` table, so I believe I either have to reference to the `Entry` table from the `Crash` table, or the other way around.

Though furthermore, what if data has not been included for race entries yet, and the `raceName` and `raceDate` pair of data only exists on the `Race` table which holds the `r_raceName` and `r_raceDate` base information.

So what I believe I may have to do is `SELECT` from the `Crash` table, and `JOIN` down to the `Entry` table, and further onto the `Race` table to truly get all `raceName` and `raceDate` pairs. Though I have no idea how I would then write a condition that says if these pairs are not present in the `Crash` table, then in my output I wish for them to be given the value of 0, or to make them present in my output at all in fact.

So I've gotten this far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.c_raceName AS raceName, 
l.c_raceDate AS raceDate, 
COUNT( l.c_raceId) AS mostCrashes 

FROM Crashes l
GROUP BY l.c_raceId
;
```

Producing the output of:

```
raceName | raceDate | mostCrashes
---------------------------------
Race 1   |2018/01/21| 1
Race 1   |2018/01/21| 3
...      | ...      | ...
```

So I've been able to separate them, into 3 and 1 as seen as above, though I only wish for the most crashes to be displayed, so the 3 row. Also I wish for all the races that did not have any crashes to be displayed as 0, rather than simply not displaying at all. So the output I'm looking for is:

```
raceName | raceDate | mostCrashes
---------------------------------
Race 1   |2018/01/21| 3
Race 2   |2018/01/21| 5
Race 1   |2018/09/11| 0
Race 1   |2016/03/14| 0
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has multiple parts.  If you want `0` values, then you need an outer join or correlated subquery.  I imagine you have a table with all the races, but a `select distinct` on the `entries` table also works.

Then if you want the most crashes *per car* you need a *car* identifier in the `crashes` table.  I'm sure one is there (it just makes sense), but you don't describe it in the question.  I'm guessing it is something like `c_raceEntryCarId`.

The resulting query looks like this:

```
select e_racename, e.e_racedate,
       (select count(*)
        from crashes c
        where c.c_racename = e.e_racename and c.e_racedate = e.e_race_date 
        group by c.c_raceEntryCarId
        order by count(*) desc
        limit 1
       ) as most_crashes
from (select e.e_racename, e.e_racedate
      from entries e
      group by e.e_racename, e.e_racedate
     ) e;
```

If you just wanted the number of crashes per race, the subquery would be a little different:

```
select e_racename, e.e_racedate,
       (select count(*)
        from crashes c
        where c.c_racename = e.e_racename and c.e_racedate = e.e_race_date
       ) as most_crashes
from (select e.e_racename, e.e_racedate
      from entries e
      group by e.e_racename, e.e_racedate
     ) e;
```

Comment: The unique identifier was `raceId` for each `raceName` and `raceDate` combination, so merely replaced `c.c_raceEntryCarId` with `c.c_raceId`.
This seems to work great though I'm not sure how the `SELECT DISTINCT` can be used to replace the `NULL` values with `0`. I've tried the IFNULL() function on the `most_crashes` `SELECT`, though it seems to have no effect on my output at all.

Will try using an outer join now.

Answer (score 1):

Please note you do not need `select distinct` when using `group by`.

```
SELECT
    l.c_raceName  AS raceName
  , l.c_raceDate  AS raceDate
  , COUNT( * )    AS mostCrashes
FROM Crashes l
GROUP BY
    l.c_raceName  
  , l.c_raceDate
HAVING COUNT( * ) = 0
OR COUNT( *) = (
    SELECT
        MAX( mostCrashes )
    FROM (
        SELECT
            l.c_raceName        AS raceName
          , l.c_raceDate        AS raceDate
          , COUNT( l.c_raceId ) AS mostCrashes
        FROM Crashes l
        GROUP BY
            l.c_raceName  
          , l.c_raceDate
    ) sq
)
ORDER BY
    mostCrashes
;
```

If you are using MySQL 8 or later you could use common table expression (cte) to simplify that.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT
        l.c_raceName AS raceName
      , l.c_raceDate AS raceDate
      , COUNT( * )   AS mostCrashes
    FROM Crashes l
    GROUP BY
        l.c_raceName  
      , l.c_raceDate
)
SELECT
    *
FROM cte
WHERE mostCrashes = ( SELECT MAX( mostCrashes ) FROM cte )
OR mostCrashes  = 0
ORDER BY
    mostCrashes
;
```

Another way, if just wanting one row, is to order the result by the calculated column (in descending order) and limit the result to one row. Y

```
SELECT
    l.c_raceName        AS raceName
  , l.c_raceDate        AS raceDate
  , COUNT( l.c_raceId ) AS mostCrashes
FROM Crashes l
GROUP BY
    l.c_raceName  
  , l.c_raceDate
ORDER BY
    mostCrashes DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

**edit**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Crashes(
>    c_raceName varchar(40)  NOT NULL
>   ,c_raceDate varchar(40)  NOT NULL
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Crashes(c_raceName,c_raceDate) 
>     VALUES
>       ('Race 1','2018/01/21')
>     , ('Race 1','2018/01/21')
>     , ('Race 1','2018/01/21')
>     , ('Race 2','2018/01/21')
>     , ('Race 2','2018/01/21')
>     , ('Race 2','2018/01/21')
>     , ('Race 2','2018/01/21')
>     , ('Race 2','2018/01/21')
>     , ('Race 1','2018/09/11')
>     , ('Race 1','2016/03/14');
>     ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     l.c_raceName        AS raceName
>   , l.c_raceDate        AS raceDate
>   , COUNT( l.c_raceDate ) AS mostCrashes
> FROM Crashes l
> GROUP BY
>     l.c_raceName
>   , l.c_raceDate
> HAVING COUNT( l.c_raceDate ) = 0
> OR COUNT( l.c_raceDate ) = (
>     SELECT
>         MAX( mostCrashes )
>     FROM (
>         SELECT
>             l.c_raceName        AS raceName
>           , l.c_raceDate        AS raceDate
>           , COUNT( l.c_raceDate ) AS mostCrashes
>         FROM Crashes l
>         GROUP BY
>             l.c_raceName
>           , l.c_raceDate
>     ) sq
> )
> ORDER BY
>     mostCrashes
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> raceName | raceDate   | mostCrashes
> :------- | :--------- | ----------:
> Race 2   | 2018/01/21 |           5
> ```

> ```
> WITH cte
> AS (
>     SELECT
>         l.c_raceName        AS raceName
>       , l.c_raceDate        AS raceDate
>       , COUNT( l.c_raceDate ) AS mostCrashes
>     FROM Crashes l
>     GROUP BY
>         l.c_raceName
>       , l.c_raceDate
> )
> SELECT
>     *
> FROM cte
> WHERE mostCrashes = ( SELECT MAX( mostCrashes ) FROM cte )
> OR mostCrashes  = 0
> ORDER BY
>     mostCrashes
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> raceName | raceDate   | mostCrashes
> :------- | :--------- | ----------:
> Race 2   | 2018/01/21 |           5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bb4717aae729cf437cff916b553e51c)*

Comment: Thank you for all this, in your first answer, what does `sq` represent?

Comment: "sq" is just a subquery alias, it might not be required in MySQL but I was validating using SQL Server where it is required

Comment: Your answer at the top doesn't actually output any information at all, I have refined and added data into my question if it makes it at all easier to understand.

Your answer runs, though no rows are output at all.

Comment: where is the data? all I see are a few rows of query output - that won't allow a query to run. You could set-up a fiddle at https://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler or https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: try these queries again.